# Why can't we manually open connection of WebSocket object after defining it's delegates?

Tags: javascript, websocket

In javacript, as soon as I define `conn=new WebSocket('url...');` it will automatically attempt to connect.

I have to define `conn.onopen=function(e){...}` to work on it. Why does this work? Should I feel safe? If so, how?

Generally in almost all platforms and programming languages we define delegates before running it, right? So why was it planned like that and not  like this: `conn=new WebSocket('...'); conn.onopen=... conn.open();`

Comment: It works because JS is single threaded and `onopen` event can't fire before current running block of code finishes whatever it does, including the declaration of handlers.

Comment: Thank you, can you post this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works because JS is single threaded and `onopen` event can't fire before current running block of code finishes whatever it does, including the declaration of handlers.

As for "why" question, well I'm not really sure.